# Python + HTML programming website order form

Tags: python, html

Hi I am working on a school project where I need to make an order form for a website using python and HTML. I am having trouble adding these:

```
if form.getvalue("interior"):
    print "<p>Interior Painting(s) quantity:", form["quantity"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,int(form["quantity"].value)*2, ".00</p>"

else:
        print "<p>Interior Painting(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("exterior"):
    print "<p>Exterior Painting quantity:", form["quantity2"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,int(form["quantity2"].value)*1, ".00</p>"

else:
        print "<p>Exterior Painting(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("pressure"):
    print "<p>Pressure Washing quantity:", form["quantity3"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,int(form["quantity3"].value)*150, ".00</p>"
else:
       print "<p>Pressure Washings(s)ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("wood"):
    print "<p>Wood Finishing quantity:", form["quantity4"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is $" ,int(form["quantity4"].value)*3, ".00</p>"
else:
        print "<p>Wood Finsihings(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("spraycan"):
    print "<p>Spray Can quantity:", form["quantity5"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is $" ,int(form["quantity5"].value)*10, ".00</p>"
else:
        print "<p>Spray Cans ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"
```

I am trying to add all the int(form[quantity..1..2].value all together and display a result after these. I have tried assigning the form[quantity].value to a varaible and adding them up but it isnt working. Also since getvalue only executes when the user selects the option, how can i go about doing this? Thanks.

FULL CODE

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# print HTTP/HTML header stuff
print """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Order Form</title>
</head><body>
"""

# print HTML body using form data
print "<h1>Profesional Painters</h1>"
print "<h2>Customer Reciept</h2>"
print "<p>Customer Name:", form["customerName"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Customer Email Address:", form["customerEmail"].value, "</p>"
print "<h2>Customer Address:</h2>"
print "<p>Street:", form["customerAdd"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>City:", form["customerCity"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Province:", form["customerProv"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Postal Code:", form["customerPostal"].value, "</p>"
print "<h2>Payment Information:</h2>"
print "<p>Card Type:", form["type1"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Card Number: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-", form["four4"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Expiry Date:", form["expirt"].value, "</p>"

print "<h2>Products Ordered</h2>"

if form.getvalue("interior"):
    print "<p>Interior Painting(s) quantity:", form["quantity"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,int(form["quantity"].value)*2, ".00</p>"

else:
        print "<p>Interior Painting(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("exterior"):
    print "<p>Exterior Painting quantity:", form["quantity2"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,int(form["quantity2"].value)*1, ".00</p>"

else:
        print "<p>Exterior Painting(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("pressure"):
    print "<p>Pressure Washing quantity:", form["quantity3"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,int(form["quantity3"].value)*150, ".00</p>"
else:
       print "<p>Pressure Washings(s)ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("wood"):
    print "<p>Wood Finishing quantity:", form["quantity4"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is $" ,int(form["quantity4"].value)*3, ".00</p>"
else:
        print "<p>Wood Finsihings(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("spraycan"):
    print "<p>Spray Can quantity:", form["quantity5"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is $" ,int(form["quantity5"].value)*10, ".00</p>"
else:
        print "<p>Spray Cans ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("email"):
    print "<p>An email notification will be sent to ",form["customerEmail"].value, "</p>"

print "</body></html>"
```

Comment: This is where it becomes a mess, separate HTML from python, use a template language, like `jinja2`.

Comment: Make HTML templates, put placeholders into it and render the templates with the appropriate context. See [Templating](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

Comment: i dont really have time to do that stuff, can someone just help me with the problem?

Comment: can you post the complete code of your py script?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on your question, the logic is to allocate calculated values to variables so you can manipulate them for a sum.

```
q1 = int(form["quantity"].value)*2
q2 = int(form["quantity2"].value)*1
q3 = int(form["quantity3"].value)*150
q4 = int(form["quantity4"].value)*3
q5 = int(form["quantity5"].value)*10

if form.getvalue("interior"):
    print "<p>Interior Painting(s) quantity:", form["quantity"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,q1, ".00</p>"

else:
    q1 = 0
    print "<p>Interior Painting(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("exterior"):
    print "<p>Exterior Painting quantity:", form["quantity2"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,q2, ".00</p>"

else:
    q2 = 0
    print "<p>Exterior Painting(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("pressure"):
    print "<p>Pressure Washing quantity:", form["quantity3"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is :$" ,q3, ".00</p>"
else:
    q3 = 0   
    print "<p>Pressure Washings(s)ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("wood"):
    print "<p>Wood Finishing quantity:", form["quantity4"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is $" ,q4, ".00</p>"
else:
    q4 = 0
    print "<p>Wood Finsihings(s) ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>"

if form.getvalue("spraycan"):
    print "<p>Spray Can quantity:", form["quantity5"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>You Cost is $" ,q5, ".00</p>"
else:
    q5 = 0
    print "<p>Spray Cans ordered: <b>0</b> <br /> Cost: <b>$0</b></p>" 

total = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5
print "<p>Total: ", total, "</p>"
```